# How can I tell if an app was purchased using Apple's volume purchase program for education?

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-vpp

I have an app that has been available in the AppStore for a while now.
I can see from the iTunes reports that it's been purchased using [Apple's volume purchase program](https://volume.itunes.apple.com/us/learn-more), which is great, however - I would like to know if a certain device is running a volume purchased app or a standard AppStore app.
I tried prying inside the receipt (`[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]`) but I couldn't find anything informative.
Creating a different bundle ID for this purpose is not an option, and kind of misses the idea of the VPP so, please - don't offer it.
Is there a programatic way to tell if the app was purchased using the VPP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were right to look inside the app receipt for VPP information, but you need to refresh it with the `SKReceiptPropertyIsVolumePurchase` flag set first:

```
self.refresh = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] initWithReceiptProperties:@{SKReceiptPropertyIsVolumePurchase : @YES}];
self.refresh.delegate = self;
[self.refresh start];
```

You then get your receipt data in `requestDidFinish:`

```
- (void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request {
    NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
    NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
    // decode receipt and examine vpp fields here 
}
```

There are [many ways](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html) to decode an apple receipt, I find the easiest way is to use Apple's receipt verifier, so I moved the receipt data to a file  (`receipt-data.der`) on my computer:

```
curl -d "{ \"receipt-data\" : \"$(base64 receipt-data.der)\" }" https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt
```

This showed some interesting new fields:

```
"organization_display_name": "ACME Bad VPPReceipt Inc."
"receipt_type": "ProductionVPPSandbox"
"expiration_date": "2015-12-10 00:44:22 Etc/GMT"
```

This is in the sandbox, so results will change when you move to production, but this should be enough to figure out if a given device is vpp or not. If you use Apple's receipt verifier, make sure to change the URL to `https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt`.

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: According to Apple's documentation, setting the VPP property is only for testing.  

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skreceiptrefreshrequest/1506038-init

Comment: I don't see anything about vpp in that link

Comment: @RhythmicFistman The documentation does say that you need to set properties to nil in production environment.